# My java project in IntelliJIdea does not detect dependencies

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

Everything was working fine until I closed the development environment. When I reopened it, the project no longer detected the lombok, spring and mongodb dependencies.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4dST.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P70vz.png)

I have searched for a thousand parts but I do not understand what is wrong so that it does not detect the dependencies when before they worked perfectly.

Comment: Refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046764/intellij-idea-not-recognizing-classes-specified-in-maven-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your project?

Right-click on the project > Maven > Reload project?