# Slow Intellij IDEA deployment (Outdated)

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

After installing new version of IDEA.14, deployment of (maven) projects significantly increased (from 15 seconds to 47 seconds).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**REASON:** IDEA uses **bundled** version of Maven

**SOLUTION:** Settings (ctrl+alt+S) --> Maven --> Maven home dir - select path to **installed** (not bundled) Maven directory

[image]

Comment: So what is the difference between the two versions?

Comment: Well... I'm not sure what was the reason, but after changing this option and unchecking checkbox "Exclude build directory" (Settings->Build Tools->Maven->Importing). Well.. one of this things solved my problem. BUT!!! Now I'm trying to undo my changes and I can't get the result that was before ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Tomcat plugin then make sure that in Tomcat Server configuration "Before Launch" doesn't contain the 'Build:artifcat' option as that's what makes it run every time even when you've done clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Changing maven, as described above, helped. Added thread count to 8 and got from 45 mins of (clean, install) to 25 minutes.
[Here before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZcxu.png),
and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMdzs.png)

The setting can be found in: Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Thread Count

[Thread count found in settings here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1uM7.png)