# Intellij idea stuck on downloading dependecy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using intellij idea 2017.3.5 ultimate edition. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.deal.padang</groupId>
<artifactId>padangdeal</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>padangDeal</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I just created a new spring boot project and it always stuck when downloading the dependency (downloading 1039/1040kb) stuck on the last few bytes.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700652/intellij-idea-taking-forever-to-resolve-maven-dependencies) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426758/intellij-idea-forge-setup-error/42427510#42427510) solution but to no avail.

I found this happen on newly clone project as well. Anyone facing the same issue?

Comment: yeah, IDEA basically fails alot using maven. Try File -> Invalidate Cache & Restart

Comment: @Gewure i have tried that, but it doesn't work either

Comment: are you on windows or linux or mac?

Comment: @Gewure i am on windows 7 64bit

Comment: i think THIS might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279859/intellij-14-1-is-too-slow-when-i-import-a-maven-project

basically its much faster if you have a native installed maven rather than using the build-in maven of IDEA.

Comment: @Gewure unfortunately it doesn't work. it stayed at the last few bytes when downloading (1159/1226 KB)

Comment: Does it work from command line? This could be a proxy/firewall/antivirus issue. Make sure to exclude IDE process, installation home, IDE [configuration folders](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519), and project, library directories from the scan.

Comment: @Andrey I tried to download it with browser and it stuck as well. I have tried using 3 different ISP, but none of them works (download stuck at 1186/1319 KB). How do i exclude IDE process and installation from proxy/firewall?

Comment: If it fails from command line/browser also this means it is not IDE-related. Must be network/firewall issue. Consult IT desk, check your windows firewall/AV configuration or check if you have any proxies in network.

Comment: @Andrey apparently not a network/firewall issue but rather issues with my windows, because it works fine in safe mode