# Intellij Maven Cannot Resolve Dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Using Intellij 15.0.1 I am trying to build a project using Maven.  However, it is not resolving any dependencies.  For example using the dependency below in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I see a message at the bottom of Intellij saying `Cannot Resolve Dependency`.  The folder `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/1.3.1` is still created in my maven repo, but there is no jar there.  Just the files`_maven.repositories  spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.pom  spark-core_2.10-1.3.1.pom.sha1`.

This behaviour is happening with any new dependency I add to the pom.

Comment: Some good troubleshooting steps here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727356/intellij-idea-cannot-resolve-anything-in-maven You may also want to post your pom, and a picture of your Intellij maven configuration screen. Also a picture of the project view of your project with the folders expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to fix the problem.  Some of the directories in `~/.m2/repository` were owned by `root` (probably from using `sudo` at some point).  Was also seeing an error along the lines of `Can't create directory at location ~/.m2/...` when running `mvn package` from the command line.

```
sudo chown -R myuser:myuser ~/.m2/repository/
```

After running this, Maven works in Intellij once again.