# Cannot resolve symbol. Maven dependencies are in place but code is in red

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I imported project from gitHub https://github.com/eugenp/spring-security-registration. It is maven based project for user management services using spring security.

I have done several times clean, install, site and reimported all dependencies. Everything is success, but my classes in red. When I enter "ALT+ENTER" it says, Add library to classpath. My IDE is Intellij

[image]

Comment: When I run project after mvn clean install it says java cannot find symbol: symbol: class EnableWebMVC etc....

Comment: can you please share your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij idea cannot resolve anything in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727356/intellij-idea-cannot-resolve-anything-in-maven)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I clicked File->Invalidate caches/restart and it solved my problem. Did not realise about this feature