# In IntelliJ, Maven can't resolve dependencies

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

Right now, I get errors on the dependencies shown in Maven.

I've tried the things listed here [Intellij idea cannot resolve anything in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727356/intellij-idea-cannot-resolve-anything-in-maven) such as changing my Maven Home Directory and Selecting Import Maven automatically. I'm not sure what else it could be...
Also, the project was initially done in Eclipse.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891. [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) will have more details about the issue.

Comment: After update the version of some dependencies in pom.xml every import was red. This helped me https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003445760/comments/360000452859

Answer (score 2):

You can try to force the downloading of dependencies with this command:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

Or you can press `Ctrl+Shift+A` (win/linux) or `Command+shift+A` (mac) to find actions, type "reimport" and choose "Reimport All Maven Projects".

From the UI:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are done with `mvn clean install`, just click this icon.

[image]

If in rare case you still face the issue type command
 `mvn -U idea:idea` (its deprecated but will do the job).

Comment: The reload-button in IntelliJ did not work for me (neither everything else I tried), but `mvn idea:idea` did the trick. Thanks, did not know that command before (even though I knew there was something like this for Eclipse, too).