# An error is displayed after declaring java-client dependency in intellij idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, appium, maven-3

I have created a new maven project. In pom.xml file, after declaring "java-client" dependency from maven repository, it's throwing an error:

***Dependency 'io.appium:java-client:8.3.0' not found***

i tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727356/intellij-idea-cannot-resolve-anything-in-maven/18064247#18064247). I couldn't resolve it. can anyone please check on this.

[image]

Comment: Does reloading all the maven projects from the Maven tool window work for you? This will download the dependencies from Maven Central repo to your local by default.

Comment: I have done that, still unable to correct this, but on online suggestion changed the maven dependency version to previous one, then the error's gone