# Maven not updating local jar (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, jar, intellij-idea

I have a local jar being imported into my project through Maven. When I update the jar in my other project, then do maven package, it is not getting updated in the main project.

I have tried everything, cleaning it, forcing dependencies, relaunching IntelliJ, deleting m2 repository, everything. Nothing is working for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Heres the code from the main project's pom.

```
    <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                    <artifactId>manager</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
```

EDIT: SOLUTION!

I accidentally had another import of the same project in my dependencies, this time not from maven. Removed that and everything was fixed.

Thanks for everybody's help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea

Comment: The project builds in maven, but not in intellij.

Comment: Did you try with `mvn install` from other project? Missing artifact is in maven repository for sure?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this.

Comment: `package`does not `install` it in your local repository

Comment: Missing library is visible in **External Libraries** view?

Comment: MariusS: Yes, Chasmo: I have also tried install

Comment: If it is vissible, then all is almost OK :) What is your problem, the attached snapshot is too old?

Comment: Its visible, but not accepting any changes. I changed some code in manager, but its not visible in my other project. I have tried the steps above.

Comment: Your changes needs to be installed into local repo with `mvn install` to be visible in other project. **BUt** you can import second project as module into Intellij. After this two projects can work without **install**

Comment: I fixed my issue. Posting solution in a sec.

Answer (score 3):

Your changes needs to be installed into local repository with `mvn install` to be visible in other project. But you can import second project as module into Intellij. After this two projects can work without **install** (internal syncing).

Documentation: [Creating and importing Maven projects](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_importing_Maven_projects)