# Intellij Cannot resolve symbol RunWith even if maven dependencies found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

My IntelliJ IDEA sees the JUnit 4 Maven dependencies.

[image: Dependecies of JUNIT in the project]

But does not resolve any symbol coming from these dependencies

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try clean/rebuilding your project as a sanity check question :)?

Comment: I didn't find any clean action, but i  use the build > Rebuild Project and it says package org.junit.runner does not exist and 4 other errors of the same kind.

Comment: This is a similar question to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579746/using-intellij-maven-to-import-libraries-cannot-resolve-symbol?rq=1

Comment: Yes and I also did both : reimport and use the same maven installation. But with no effect.

Comment: `junit` in `test` scope and `BookSearchTest` test class under source directory (`src/main/java`) ?

Comment: I finally build the project with eclipse and reimport in Inteliji. No class path problem anymore. So it's solved, I guess i missed something during the creation of the project. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I followed these steps and was able to code a `TestCase` with Intellij code insight.

In a shell, I did the following

```
mkdir so33987661
mkdir so33987661/src/
mkdir so33987661/src/test
mkdir so33987661/src/test/java
cd so33987661
vi pom.xml
```

My `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.so33987661</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Back to Intellij, choose **File** menu, **New**, **Project from Existing Sources**.

Open the `so33987661/pom.xml` file.

Check the **Import Maven Projects Automatically**.
[image]

Accept the defaults for the rest of the screens by clicking **Next** until the project is created.

Navigate to the `src/test/java` folder and create a new test and code, code, code.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class BookSearchTest {

    @Test
    public void testIt() throws Exception {
        // todo: testIt()!
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I delete the .idea file and reimport the project, the problem was fixed then. That was my firts try of intellij I guessed I mess something. I can't remember if "Import Maven Projects Automatically" was checked when this problem happened, but it is now.Thanks anyway.

Comment: For me, this solution worked even without reimporting project (just unchecking and checking back Import automatically.. choice).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
Open your pom.xml, find "junit". See scope value, maybe 'test'.
if u import junit in main package, intellij idea will throw error, but not eclipse.
Use junit in right scope can solve the problem.
I fixed my error.

Comment: That was not the case, the test was in the standard directory, the project was a classical maven project.

Comment: I'm not sure my scope was test but if it was a standard scope it should be seen in a test. I delete the .idea and reimport the project without changing anything else and the problem solved out. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**#
1** check in **settings -> build, execution, deployment -> build tools -> maven**, if "User settings file" and (if you are using local repo) "Local repository" paths are set correctly.

**#
2** check in **settings -> build, execution, deployment -> compiler -> java compiler** if target bytecode version is that you expecting. (sometimes after adding new dependency Intelli is setting it to 1.5)

**#
3** in project settings (default shortcut ctrl+alt+shift+s) **project settings -> project**

- ProjectSDK should point to correct destination
- Project language level should be version that you are using

in **project settings -> modules** Language Level should be version that you are using

Comment: Thanks for this answers, that will be useful later on but as I said in my previous comment I rebuilt the project and the problem solved out.