# IntelliJ cannot resolve Spark external libraries

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, import

I'm trying to setup Apache Spark project (pulled lastest master branch) in my IntelliJ

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.5
Build #IC-162.2228.15, built on October 14, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-287-b2 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

And all import libs failed from IntelliJ "external libraries" section 
[image]

I've tried `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart` and `maven window reimport button`, and other suggestions from [Using Intellij + Maven to import libraries: Cannot resolve symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579746/using-intellij-maven-to-import-libraries-cannot-resolve-symbol) and [Intellij Cannot resolve symbol on import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952078/intellij-cannot-resolve-symbol-on-import), but still not working.

I just guess I have some mis-config of my IntelliJ? And I also have warning `Project spark: there is circular dependency between 'main5' module, 'main27' module` maybe this is the root cause?
Thanks a lot.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rm -rf spark/`
seems existing cache files are causing conflicts or so

maybe could also use `sbt clean build`