# Can't find google package "com.google.cloud.speech.v1beta1"

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to use the Google Cloud Speech API to recognize speech.
I'm following the example code at

> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/grpc

I already done with run `mvn package` but I can't find the `com.google.cloud.speech.v1beta1` package that is used in the Spring MVC application.

[Can resolve the com.google.cloud.speech.v1beta1 package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FOkT.png)

How i find this package or how i can use it in Spring MVC maven project ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**You have missed the jar files.**

### For Eclipse user,

For this, you can go to your console. Then go to the project folder where pom.xml.

Then run this 2 command,

```
mvn eclipse:clean
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

### For intellij users,

[full clean-up and restarting procedure:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea)

1. Close your project window (and IntelliJ) and remove all `*.iml` files
   and all `.idea` folders (there should be one per module)
2. Run `mvn clean install` from the command line
3. Re-import the project into IntelliJ and pay attention when it asks
   you to enable auto-import

Comment: Thats my pleasure. You are most welcome in SO @RObert_Duy