# import hadoop source code to intellij

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

[image]I want to import hadoop source code 2.7.2 in intellij IDe .
I do like this :
file -existing project - maven -choose pom.xml in hadoop 2.7.2. source file -after import I get error in maven project view .

does any body know what to do?
I read [Import Maven dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea)  .but it did not work .
thank

Comment: what is that error?? can you please put  screenshot?

Comment: does my path to import  correct?

Comment: when importing, after you chose Maven, in the next window, have you ticked 'Import Maven projects automatically' ??

Comment: yes I ticked import maven projects automatically, after imported it downloaded sources and documentations .

Comment: what are your intellij and java versions??

Comment: intellij 2016 -java 1.8

Comment: I have added my answer, please try and update. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with PSI caches.

So try **File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart..**

NOTE: This one will wipe out any shelved changes.

I assume you won't have that problem because you are still in importing project.