# Maven not importing External Library into project after adding to .pom file in Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm having trouble correctly importing a library into a project that I'm running. I have added the library as a dependency in the `.pom`, refreshed the pom, run `mvn clean install`, and I have set `auto-import` up so that the project gets updated correctly, but the project does not get added as an External Library, and I can't use it in my project. I get no errors. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the relevant part of my pom

```
 ..properties
 <crowd.version>2.5.0</crowd.version>
 .. end properties

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.crowd</groupId>
        <artifactId>crowd-integration-springsecurity</artifactId>
        <version>${crowd.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Here is the question I was following to debug my error: 
[Import Maven dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: nothing, unfortunately

Comment: Is this dependency in maven central or any other repo that you refer to in your settings.xml. [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.crowd/crowd-integration-springsecurity) shows some crazy dependency version :-).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have tried `compile` and `test` based off your suggestion, but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the point of dependency management; read more in [official docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management). This is a feature that you can centralize common dependency information that is then shared been different projects. All by itself, this definioition will **not** import the dependency.

What you probably want is just a plain dependency: drop the `dependencyManagement` tags, and move you dependency into the correct block in the pom.