# Importing new framework in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, frameworks, dependencies

I wanted to install add a new library. And I already added this dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

but I am not able to and I do not know why

[image]

i need it for that code:

```
String hashpwd = BCrypt.hashpw(benutzer.getPasswort(),BCrypt.gensalt());
benutzer.setPasswort(hashpwd);
```

but BCrypt is always red and if i hover over it there is written cannot resolve symbol

Comment: You might forget to define version of artifact.

Comment: but even if i define it the whole thing is red

Comment: and i want to use it therefore: String hashpwd = BCrypt.hashpw(benutzer.getPasswort(),BCrypt.gensalt());
            benutzer.setPasswort(hashpwd);

Comment: but it does not work

Comment: If you've defined the version then your example should show that. Otherwise people will focus on the fact you haven't specified the version. Note that `RELEASE` is not a valid version—it used to be, in Maven 2, but not anymore.

Comment: ok thanks i will change an repost it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-importing the dependencies? You have to manually re-import the dependencies when the enable auto-import option is not enabled in IntelliJ.

The reimport button can be found in the Maven tab to the right in IntelliJ:
[image]

Comment: I tried importing your dependency-setup and all went fine. I kind of fail at reproducing your problem. Have you, by any chance, come across this post which seemed to have a similar issue? https://stackoverflow.com/q/11454822/7804385

Comment: could you tell me step by step what you did. maybe i missed something

Comment: if i click at the .idea > libraries folder there are a lot which ones do you have there?

Comment: Well I created a Maven test project which has one module named my-app, the same you see on the picture in my answer. I then entered each and every <dependency></dependency> that is seen on your image of dependencies into the <dependencies></dependencies> tag in the pom.xml file of the module. I have auto-import enabled, so the dependencies auto downloaded, but I also tried it without the auto-import and it worked fine as well.

Comment: ok thank you I also did all those steps and I really do not know why it does not work for me

Comment: What I might suggest is Invalidating cache, menu File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... That might do the trick

Comment: which version do you have

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2019.2.2

Comment: Hm, maybe you can try to create another project, import the same dependencies in the new project and have a look at the differences between the `<project_module>.iml` file folder of the mps-rest project and the new project.

Comment: Have you checked idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") for errors?