# RED lines in Maven POM

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

I have red lines in my POM file even after followed below solutions.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>tek</groupId>
<artifactId>rest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>rest</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
        <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
        <version>2.24.1</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

[Solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea)

I noticed below in my IDE. Is that something I should worry about?

[image]

Error when run in command line

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Further, when I tried to open the `pom.xml` directly as a project I get notification pop-up in intellij `Non-managed pom.xml file found:` Not sure this is related. After set the `POM.xml` as Maven Project. Then back to same red lines there in the POM.

Is there other alternative way of adding those dependency manually if automatic import doesn't work?

`Setting.xml`

[image]

Comment: If you build the project with `mvn clean verify`, does it work? If not, what errors appear on the command line?

Comment: @JFMeier I added the error to the question. `mvn clean verify` gives the same error in command line.

Comment: Hm, `https` has been enforced lately across nearly all if not all maven repos. Does your `settings.xml` in the `.m2` directory have an `http` URL? If you visit the `http` version of `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/` it'll throw a 501

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I added repository section into the question. I don't have `http` version there. Neither `https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/`. Does that mean I need to have maven rul's there under repository section in `setting.xml` file? As you can see the `POM.xml` in the question I have url with `http:`. Does that cause the issue?

Comment: Ignoring IntelliJ for now. From a CLI, with mvn on the classpath can you try running the `mvn verify -X`, `-x` adds debug output and might let us find where the issue is. Also unknown host, is a strange one...

Comment: The error "Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org" is certainly concerning. Does your machine have access to the Internet?

Comment: @Darren Forsythe with more debug `ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom. Return code is: 501, ReasonPhrase: HTTPS Required. -> [Help 1] `

Comment: @SiKing After switching to my private network it gives above error.

Comment: there's something causing the `http` instead of `https` connections to the apache maven repo. If outside if a private network it works you might have to work with your org to find what is causing it. 

Could try to ensure you don't have any `http` repos set on your end, but seems unlikely if its not in your `pom` or `settings.xml`.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe As mentioned in the above logs, even switch to private network I get `501`. So where should I check whether I have `http` repos?

Comment: Oh sorry, assumed private was your companies VPN or similar. See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html `downloading from a Remote repository`.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I added `<repository>
            <id>maven-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>` to `setting.xml` and I am on my private network. Still getting `501`. Logs indiacte `http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2` without `https`. Can you please shed some light there?

Comment: @SiKing Yes, it works when I switch to personal network. But still when switch to corporate network. It throws `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project api-automation: Could not resolve dependencies for project api-automation:api-automation:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:jar:2.3.1 (compile), junit:ju
nit:jar:4.12 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3: Could not transfer artifact org.ow2:ow2:pom:1.3 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.m`