# Have lost the oppotunity of java package import

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import

Unexpectedly my apps have lost opportunity of java-package import.

For example I write "import java.io.File" in a top of java-class.  And "java" in this expression is underlined in red.

I checked Project Structure:
Project SDK is: 11 java version 11.0.5.  In other places of Project Structure java 11 is specified too.

[image: ProjStr]

[image: Class]

[image: PV]

Comment: What IDE is this?

Comment: can you show the actual class? Maybe just the location you are adding your import statement is wrong?

Comment: Intellij IDEA. Last version.  And the problem concerning of all classes in all projects

Comment: maybe the source root is something like `src/main/java`, and you have `src/main/java/a/b/C.java`. Then the first line must be `package a.b;`, and then imports.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot of your Project View drilled down to the class you are having this error in and its code visible.

Comment: Screens attached

Comment: Looks like the JDK is not specified correctly in the module settings. Please select your module in Project Structure | Modules and ensure that the JDK is correctly specified there.

Answer (score 0):

The module `java.base` does not [export](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#module-declarations) the package `java`, so the types `java.io.*` and `java.util.*` are not [accessible](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#accessibility).

You can export the package by hovering over the red 'java' word (or placing your caret on it and hitting `Alt+Enter`) and choosing the corresponding action:

[image]

or adding the following line to the **File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler** options:

```
--add-exports java.base/java=ALL-UNNAMED
```

[image: IntelliJ IDEA: Override compiler parameters per module]

Comment: Done this. Then invalidate caches and restarted Idea.   But with the same result...

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев After you've added the option, what does the error say if you hover over the red word?

Comment: "java" in this import-expressions is underlined in red.

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев Слово подчеркнуто волнистой линией или целиком красное? Что говорит всплывающая подсказка, если вы наведете курсор на 'java' в import expression?

Точно ли указан Module SDK на **Project Structure | Modules > Dependencies tab**?

В **Project Structure | SDKs** проверьте, что JDK home path верный и классы в Classpath ниже находятся и возвращаются. Если Classpath пустой, проверьте путь к JDK: возможно, выбрана одна из подпапок в корневой папке с установленной Java.

Comment: Целиком красное. При наведении курсора предлагает добавить maven-зависимость

Comment: @АндрейДмитриев Проверьте, что нужная зависимость прописана в pom.xml. Все нужные Maven зависимости должны быть там прописаны. Если зависимость есть в pom, попробуйте переимпортить проект с панели Maven в Идее (r-click на проекте > Reimport). Идея должна автоматически скачать и настроить все зависимости из вашего pom файла. Если скачивания по какой-то причине не происходит, попробуйте запустить `mvn install` из командной строки.

Comment: Также см. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea и https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html