# IntelliJ Dependency not found: mysql-connector-java

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, dependencies

I am having an issue in which IntelliJ is not recognising the mysql-connector dependency in my pom.xml file. It appears as red and displays 'Dependency 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.25' not found'. I don't have to download anything, do I? Is declaring the dependency in pom.xml enough? I am also getting the same for the maven-failsafe-plugin.

My pom.xml file dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.25</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

If anyone has any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That should work, Maven will automatically download the necessary library when you build it. Try building the project with Maven (`mvn clean install`, or by clicking it in the Maven panel in IntelliJ).

Comment: Thank you, reloading the project with maven fixed the issue!

Comment: Find the answer in here (as @Jesper comment)? [Import Maven dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea)

Answer (score 4):

I think they have recently changed in dependency MySQL.
My issue was resolved by adding the below dependency.You can also try it

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```