# Java and intelij idea

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I don't know if there is something that I am not doing or not. Everything I try to do with intelij gives me errors. For instance, creating a javafx application is a problem. Now I am trying to create a vaadin project and I am getting this:
[image]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDmLT.png
I've tried installing all maven dependencies but still I am getting errors. Intelij idea is the best java ide currently and I would also like to use it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's because the required dependencies are not available. Make sure you added required dependencies in pom.xml and wait till the build is complete within IDE. It takes a while to download the dependencies.

Something like "downloading shared dependencies for maven library ..." should be visible in the toolbar area of the IDE. Let it complete this step for all the dependencies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import Maven dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11467266/19170534)

Comment: It shows that all dependencies are installed but when I try to run the application, It is not giving me a localhost port 8080. When I also create a MainView class, it does not recognise vaadin classes and functions and gives errors.

Comment: Try deleting the target folder and do a re import of all your dependencies. You could also try with tha "maven" tab on the right, there are options there to refresh your dependencies.