# Cannot resolve symbol 'gargoylesoftware' even when htmlunit dependancy is present under pom.xml

Tags: intellij-idea, htmlunit

pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.70.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Usage in test.java file

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
```

Getting error "Cannot resolve symbol 'gargoylesoftware'" in IntelliJ 2022.1.3.

I have run command `mvn install` from the command line under this project directory to make sure all the dependancies mentioned in the pom.xml are downloaded.

Comment: Please check that library in mentioned in module dependencies ("Project Structure  | Modules - Dependencies")

Comment: can you share screenshot, as I'm not finding Modules - Dependencies under Project Structure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea per this I had deleted .idea and .iml files and later ran command "mvn install", now I could see lots of errors

Comment: Have you clicked on "Reload" in maven tools window?