# How to import maven dependancies 2022.3.2 ( Mac OS )

Tags: intellij-idea

I've tried all the answers mentioned under [Import Maven dependencies in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454822/import-maven-dependencies-in-intellij-idea) but none of them worked till now.

I tried both options from inside IntelliJ as well running commands from command line.

Comment: Could you please clarify your case? Do you mean that dependencies in pom.xml are not recognised in source code?

Comment: yes, none of the dependancies are recognized in source code. I don't know how to resolve this blocking issue. Checked multiple SO posts but none helped so far.

Comment: Have you tried to run "Reload" from Maven tool window? Are dependencies shown in "Project Structure | Modules | <Module name> - Dependencies"?